# Issuing Partial Refunds in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I need to be able to refund single items from orders containing multiple items. Currently, I can delete a unwanted item from an order, but my only option for returning funds to the customer appears to be refunding the entire order and then creating a new payment for the new amount owing.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to do it from the Store CP; depending on what payment gateway you are using I have found that it is usually easier to do it from the payment gateway actual account portal.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. We’re using Stripe as our payment gateway, and it does allow for partial refunds. Unfortunately, I still need to manually adjust order details (and inventory) on the Expresso Store side of things, as the transaction details do not get passed back from Stripe.

Comment: Hopefully in a future version of Store partial transactions will be possible or at least hooks will be added to allow user to implement their own gateway because I don't think any of the of the current transaction hooks would work. https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html#transaction_hooks but y